# how to open two modal in the same div in angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8

I have a DIV and in the div, there is a link. Now when I click `modalA()`. It opens `modalA()`, `modalB()` and when I click `modalB()`. It opens `modalB()` and `modalA()`. because Both methods are in the same div. So When I click `modalA()`. It should open `modalA()` only.  When I click `modalB()`. It should open `modalB()` only. please give me your suggesstion.

```
<div class="a" (click)="modalA()">
  <a (click)="modalB()"> </a>
</div>

modalA() {
  console.log('A modal');
}

modalB() {
  console.log('B modal');
}
```

Comment: here is demo hope will help you https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-dialog?file=app%2Fexample%2Fexample.component.ts

Comment: @santosh shinde I did not understand it. could you please explain me about it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [event.stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

Try like this:

```
modalB() {
  window.event.stopPropagation();
  console.log("B modal");
}
```

or,

.html

```
<div class="a" (click)="modalA()"> aaaa
  <a (click)="modalB($event)">bbbb </a>
</div>
```

.ts

```
modalB(evt) {
  evt.stopPropagation();
  console.log("B modal");
}
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-master-ydbrzc)**